# How to pass Guid.Empty into a parameterized unit test?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

I'm attempting to pass Guid.Empty into my unit test:

```
[TestCase(null)]
[TestCase(Guid.Empty)]
public void When_AccountGuid_IsNullOrEmpty_AddError_Is_Invoked(Guid? accountGuid)
{

}
```

However the compiler is complaining:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

**How do I pass Guid.Empty into my unit test method?**

I've also tried to factor it out by declaring it as a private member in the class, with the same compiler error:

```
        private static Guid _emptyGuid = Guid.Empty;
        [TestCase(null)]
        [TestCase(_emptyGuid)]
        public void When_AccountGuid_IsNullOrEmpty_AddError_Is_Invoked(Guid? accountGuid)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In this situation use the [`TestCaseSource`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseSource-Attribute) atribute to define the list of cases.

```
static Guid?[] NullAndEmptyGuid = new Guid?[] { null, Guid.Empty };

[TestCaseSource("NullAndEmptyGuid")]
public void When_AccountGuid_IsNullOrEmpty_AddError_Is_Invoked(Guid? accountGuid)
{

}
```

Comment: Can you use multiple `TestCaseSource`?  Would be nice to add that to the code example.  Also can use `nameof` instead of string.

Answer (score 2):

Use **DynamicData** instead of **DataRow** for the .Net Testing Framework (`Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`):

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("")]
[DataRow(" ")]
[DataRow(0)]
[DynamicData(nameof(DynamicDefaultValues), DynamicDataSourceType.Property)]
public void IsValid_WithInvalidInput_ShouldReturnFalse(object input)
{
    // Validate
}


private static IEnumerable<object[]> DynamicDefaultValues
{
    get
    {
        yield return new object[] { Guid.Empty };
        yield return new object[] { DateTime.MinValue };
     }
}
```

Note: you could also use a specific parameter type instead of `object` if they are all from the same type.

> public void IsValid_WithInvalidInput_ShouldReturnFalse(**Guid** input)

Answer (score -3):

Empty is a variable actually and you can not pass variables in attributes.
Expressions are required to be constants, try to pass a "new Guid()" OR default(Guid)

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe `new Guid()` and `default(Guid)` will still give the same compilation error.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - just tested it myself after your comment and, yep, same error :)

Comment: `Guid` is not an attribute parameter type and `Guid` (or even more interestingly `decimal`) can't be used as attribute parameters.

Comment: @BryanWoodford Wow, I was so sure `default` would have worked, but just did a test myself and it did not. I deleted my old comments

Comment: I thought default(Guid) would be known at compile time and pass that check. Did not actually test it, i had no pc available :S oh well...